# developing custodial vs non-custodial wallets

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

This is a very broad and general question so I'm going to specify my intended use case and branch several questions, mainly referring to the implementation of each approach.

In short, users using my wallet are going to constantly send to each other, and perhaps receive/send from/to other wallets and networks, and I'm mentioning this in case it could provide an overview of how transactions will take place in my app.

so to start with the custodial wallets:from what i know, most custodial wallets have 1 cold wallet and 1 hot wallet and a hot wallet to every user, so when a user creates an account keys are automatically generated to that user, but my question is how are the users' keys stored: is it in a normal db or do they do it in another way, and how does this model work like how do they technically use the cold and hot wallets.

moving to non-custodial wallets,i want to know basically the same thing, how and where are the users' keys stored? and how are they accessed? and in case i go with this approach i am still able to impose tx fees on tx happening on my app?

I hope I made sense in what I said, and I hope to check your answers, If you feel like you know an answer to some part of the question but not all that okay say what you know as any contribution would be great, and if anyone is up for a discord/zoom call i would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance, and please let me know in case you need extra info to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *custodial wallets*
>
> *how are the users' keys stored*

It depends on each app implementation. A good practice is to store sensitive data (such as private keys) in a secrets management system. It's usually an encrypted database with advanced access control - allowing access to groups of data based on user group policies, generating single-use or time-sensitive tokens for accessing the data, ... The application can then request the private key from the SMS using the user's unique token.

> *non-custodial wallets*
>
> *how and where are the users' keys stored? and how are they accessed?*

Software wallets (including browser extensions) usually store private keys in a file, located in your computer, encrypted by a master key. The master key can be for example the hash of your MetaMask password and some predefined salt. When you unlock the wallet by entering the correct password, the wallet software decrypts the file containing the actual private keys, and then it's able to use the private keys.

Hardware wallets store private keys on the device, encrypted by a master key as well (e.g. your device PIN and a salt). It's a common practice that private keys never leave the device. So the UI software usually sends a request to sign a raw transaction data to the device, the device then asks the user to enter their pin, performs the signature on the actual device and returns the signed transaction back to the UI software.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i also want to know, if i go with the non-custodial approach, am i able to follow a certain scheme that permits me to register users and identify users by username/password?

Comment: @whitebat199 You can have them register in your app first, have them input their address, and then have them sign a predefined message (using a private key corresponding to the input address, stored in their non-custodial wallet). Your app can then verify if the message was signed from the provided address, using a zero-knowledge proof algorithm. Examples: [on-chain](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/utilities#cryptography), [off-chain](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-personal.html#ecrecover). This way, you'll be able to provably connect the address to the username.

Comment: Thanks again petr, please check your email when you can and respond at your convenience.